# Thanos' motives

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war, avengers-endgame

Throughout phases 3-4 of the MCU, Thanos tries to, and succeeds in wiping out half of all existence.

He says this is due to overpopulation (a different motive from the comics), but *Eternals* tells us it was to stop The Emergence happening on Earth.

So, my 2-part question:

1. Why did he lie about his true reasoning?
2. Why did he eradicate all life, and not just Earth's?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> the Eternals tells us it was to stop the emergence happening on Earth.

### Actually, No

You are operating under a false premise. The Eternals makes no statement that Thanos was trying to stop the emergence.

I think you are missing the thrust of what this quote actually means.

> Five years ago, Thanos erased half of the population of the universe. Delayed the emergence.

That's what happened, it does not mean that Thanos **intended** to delay the emergence even assuming he knew about it. Killing 50% of the worlds population just had the *effect* of delaying the emergence, it wasn't his plan to do that.